# How to define template function overload to match empty std::tuple<>?

Tags: c++, templates, c++14

I'd like to distinguish between empty and non-empty tuples, and I came up with the following solution ([example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2c4b5bb942068db3)):

```
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>

template <typename ... Args>
void function(const std::tuple<Args...>& t)
{
    std::cout << "empty tuple" << std::endl;
}

template <typename Head, typename ... Args>
void function(const std::tuple<Head, Args...>& t)
{
    std::cout << "tuple of size: " << sizeof...(Args) + 1 << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    function(std::make_tuple());  // picks 1st function
    function(std::make_tuple(1)); // picks 2nd function
    function(std::make_tuple(1, 2, 3, '4')); // picks 2nd function
}
```

However, using variadic `Args` to match `std::tuple<>` is misleading for a reader, and I think that introducing `Head` in the 2nd overload is excessive. Is there a simple way to write an overload that matches `std::tuple<>` directly?

Comment: If you were defining a class template, the primary template would have to accept `typename ... Args`, but a partial specialization could restrict to the case with `Head`.  With functions, you're defining two overloaded (unrelated) templates; there's no reason to have _both_ of them able to handle non-empty parameter packs.

Comment: thanks @DavisHerring

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try:

```
void function(const std::tuple<>& t) { ... }
```

?

Then you don't need to write `Head` out separately in the second function. Live example: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1806c3a8a3e6b2d1.

Comment: yep, thanks, it works for this example. I had problems in a broader example, and `const std::tuple<>&` overload didn't work there. I'll probably post it as a separate question